# Query to find Parent entity by Child attribute where Parent also have same attritube, in spring data jpa

Tags: spring-data-jpa

I am trying to create a query in Spring-data-jpa to find a `Person` entity by `Address`'s `id`. `Person` have OneToOne relationship with `Address` and both have `id` as primary key.

```
public abstract class AbstractEntity{
     @Id
     Long id;
}


public class Person extends AbstractEntity {
    @OneToOne
    Address address;
}


public class Address extends AbstractEntity {

}

public interface PersonRepository implements JpaRepository<Person, Long> {

    Person findByAddressId(Long addressId); // Throws cannot create metamodel exception

    Person findByAddress_Id(Long addressId); // Throws cannot create metamodel exception

}
```

I'm thinking that the method name `findByAddressId` and `findByAddress_Id` are ambiguous for Spring data jpa query look-up strategies as both `Person` and `Address` entities have `id` as their attributes.

**Is it possible to write query in Spring-data-jpa to find  parent entity by child attribute where parent and child both have same attribute, without writing SQL?**

Comment: Did you ever get this to work?  I am facing the same issue.

Comment: Nope. This approach is confusing to read code as well as don't give much of type safety. I prefer writing JPA `@Query` and QueryDSL.

Comment: I agree.  That is what I ending up deciding myself! ;)